# Partial Differential Equations- General solution with different separation constants

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

So I have the wave equation

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} $$

and I know the process to split it into the two ODE's which are

$F''(x)-nF(X) = 0$ (Used $n$ because I couldn't find $\lambda$, where $n$ is the separation constant)

$$G''(t) - c^2nG(t)=0$$

I know how to go on from there when the separation constant is $<0$
However I am unsure what happens when the separation constant is $= 0$ or $> 0$

Comment: Where are your boundary conditions? By the way you will have trivial solutions for $n=0$ and $n>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For $n=0$

Your ode equation for $F(x)$ will become
$$F''(x)=0$$
which gives
$$F(x)=Ax+B$$
Now we do not know your boundary conditions but let say $F(0)=0=F(L)$,
then $F(x)=0$, a trivial solution.

2. For $n>0$

The ode for $F(x)$ will have the characteristics equation of the form $r^2-n=0$ with the roots $r=\pm n$ and thus the solution is

$$F(x)=C\exp{(\sqrt{n}x)}+D\exp{(-\sqrt{n}x)}$$

let say with homogeneous boundary conditions of the first type, again we will endup with trivial solution.

3. For $n<0\,\, (\mbox{say} -\lambda^2)$

The characteristic equation in this case is $r^2+\lambda^2=0$ with imaginary roots $r=\pm \iota \lambda$ then the solution to the ode is
$$F(x)=A_1\cos{(\lambda\,x)}+B_{1}\sin{(\lambda x)}$$
Now utilizing one the the three types of boundary conditions (say first type), we will have $A_1=0$ and for nontrivial solution we will take $B_1\neq0$, thus
\begin{align}
\sin{(\lambda L)}=0\\
\Rightarrow \lambda L = \sin^{-1}{(0)}\\ 
\Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{n_1\pi}{L},\,\, n_1=1,2,3...
\end{align}
Finally,  $F(x)=B_{n_1}\sin{(\frac{n_1\pi}{L} x)}$. Subbing the eignvalues into the temporal equation $G(t)$, we get 
$$G''(t)-c^2\frac{n_1\pi}{L}G(t)=0$$
I think you can solve for $G(t)$.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you very much!